# @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedure

Dentro de un formulario tengo 9 Checkbox, estoy usando el Helper Html.CheckBoxFor para almacenarlos en una DB, pero aun seleccionados no cambia el valor a true, dentro del modelo los tengo declarados así:

```
public Boolean AS { get; set; }
public Boolean AR { get; set; }
public Boolean AB { get; set; }
public Boolean AX { get; set; }
public Boolean TM { get; set; }
public Boolean TF { get; set; }
public Boolean TR { get; set; }
public Boolean TT { get; set; }
public Boolean TY { get; set; }
```

Dentro del formulario en cshtml lo implemento así:

```
<label class="text-primary">Análisis de la causa principal</label>
                <div class="form-check" name= "Analisis">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id = "AS" name="AS" value=@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.AS)/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Errores: S</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="AR" name="AR" value=@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.AR, false)/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Servicios: R</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="AB" name="AB" value=@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.AB)/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Falla de componente: B</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="AX" name="AX" value=@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.AX)/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Desconocido: X</label>
                </div>
```

Y en el metodo post los llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Boolean AS, Boolean AR, Boolean AB, Boolean AX, Boolean TM, Boolean TF, Boolean TR, Boolean TT, Boolean TY, Boolean GM, Boolean GF, Boolean GR, Boolean GT, Boolean GY)
{
//manipulacion
}
```

Tengo más elementos dentro de mi formulario y de igual forma dentro del metodo post, para esos elementos si esta recogiendo los datos, donde no veo por que no los recupera es en los check´s

Adicional, no veo porque marca como parte del html los 2 ultimos caracteres del helper "/>"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se guarda como un BIT

Comment: Aca no se dan ni ejemplos ni guias.. que problema particular tuviste haciendolo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comento lo que a mi me funciono, use la propiedad asp-for, tomando como referencia este articulo https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#razor-checkboxes , quedando mi código del lado de cshtml así:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="text-primary">Tratamiento</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="TM"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Correción: M</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for=TF/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Pulverización: F</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for=TR/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Cambio: R</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for=TT/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Relacionado a test: T</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for=TY/>
                    <label class="form-check-label">Productos de medición de capacitancia: Y</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Fue lo único que modifique y ahora ya tengo cuales checkbox fueron marcados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]